# How to convert Zulu time format to datetime format in PySpark?

Tags: python, sql, date, datetime, pyspark

I am trying to convert a column that contains Zulu formatted timestamps to a typical datetime format. This is an example of the format the dates are in: 1533953335000.

So far, I have been using this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t
df=df.withColumn('DTMZ',f.date_format(df.DTMZ.cast(dataType=t.TimestampType()), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
df=df.withColumn('DTMZ', f.to_date(df.DTMZ.cast(dataType=t.TimestampType())))
```

My output when I use the above code is: 50579-01-17

I am hoping to be able to view these dates in a typical readable format.

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Datetime  in Python (and most languages and databases) has no format, it's a binary type. What do you mean by Zulu time? ISO-8601 with a Z suffix? That's not a different format, `Z` is equivalent to `+00:00`. It's what people call UTC.

Comment: Does `timestamps` refer to a UNIX timestamp? That's not a different type or format, that's a float or integer offset since 1970-01-01. It's converted to a `datetime` using [datetime.fromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)

Comment: you zhave a utc that makes your t9imestamp Saturday, 11. August 2018 02:08:55  s oll for conversion utc and set the right timezone

Comment: Thank you for all of your responses. This has helped immensely. And as to your question about Zulu time, I am fairly new to it myself, but I believe it is just another term for unix time specifically for use in aviation and shipping to avoid timezone differences.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime` in Python and most languages and databases is a binary type, it has no format. Python has no `timestamp` type. The value 1533953335000 looks to be a UNIX timestamp, an offset since 1970-01-01.Normally that's in seconds but in this case it seems it's in milliseconds.

You can convert a UNIX timestamp to a `datetime` using [datetime.fromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp). 1533953335000 must be divided by 1000 first because `fromtimestamp` expects seconds :

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1533953335000/1000)
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 11, 5, 8, 55)
```

This returns a local time. Zulu is sometimes used to refer to UTC/+00:00 [for historical reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones) :

> The time zone using UTC is sometimes denoted UTC±00:00 or by the letter Z—a reference to the equivalent nautical time zone (GMT), which has been denoted by a Z since about 1950. Time zones were identified by successive letters of the alphabet and the Greenwich time zone was marked by a Z as it was the point of origin. The letter also refers to the "zone description" of zero hours, which has been used since 1920 (see time zone history). Since the NATO phonetic alphabet word for Z is "Zulu", UTC is sometimes known as "Zulu time". This is especially true in aviation, where "Zulu" is the universal standard

To get UTC time, the [datetime.utcfromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) function is used :

```
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1533953335000/1000)
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 11, 2, 8, 55)
```

Notice that the results are identical. Both methods return [naive objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects), ie objects with no timezone information. There's no way to tell if this is local or UTC, summer or winter time. The timezone must be passed explicitly to get an "aware" object :

```
>>> from datetime import timezone
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1533953335000/1000,timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 11, 2, 8, 55, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Other languages and databases have explicit timezone-aware types, eg `datetimeoffset`

Comment: Notice that the above does not give you an [aware](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) datetime object. Be careful if you want to operate across timezones: by definition a [`timestamp` is in UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and as such you ought to construct an aware datetime: `datetime.fromtimestamp(1533953335000/1000, tz=timezone.utc)`. See also [`datetime.timezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone).

Comment: I was writing just that